# v.reclass no output

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, vector, qgis-processing, reclassify

I want to reclassify a polygon vector and use v.reclass.

Feature type: boundary

Name of column: LBA

Reclass Rule: I use a .txt with the following content:

```
CASE
WHEN  LBA  = 68 THEN 2
WHEN  LBA  = 69 THEN 1
ELSE NULL
END
```

There is no result and no error message...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the code you typed is not suitable for [v.reclass](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.reclass.html) but for Field calculator in QGIS. In any case, you should add double quotes and single quotes to your code:

- double quotes for column names: `"LBA"`
- single quotes for values if they are in a *varchar* columns: `'68'`
- if the LBA column or the column that will save your reclassified values is an *integer/real/double columns*, single quotes are not necessary.

  ```
  CASE
    WHEN "LBA" = 68 THEN 2
    WHEN "LBA" = 69 THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END
  ```